# add a button to open a modal window inside a listview on kendoui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I need to add a button, on each element of a Listview (PHP/Json) result, to open a modal window, where the customer can enter his reservation information, as Date, Adults and Childrens, here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                pageSize: 8,
                transport: {
                    read: "tours_lista.php",
                         dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                schema: {   
                    data: "data",
                    total: "data.length"
                }

            });

        $("#pager").kendoPager({
            dataSource: dataSource,


        });

        $("#listView").kendoListView({
            dataSource: dataSource,

            template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
        });

    });
```

and here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="intro" >
    <H3>TOURS</H3>
<div id="listView"></div>
<div id="pager" class="k-pager-wrap"></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
  <div class="product">
       <a class="t-link"  href="inicio.php?action=detalle&tourid=${recid}"><img  src="controlc/test/${main_pic}" title="Ver detalles de ${tit_esp}" /></a>
        <h3>${tit_esp}</h3>
        <dl>
            <dt>Adulto: </dt>
            <dd>$ ${rate_adult}</dd>
            <dt>Niño: </dt>
            <dd>$ ${rate_child}</dd>

        </dl>
         <div style="text-align:right;float:right;border:0px solid red;padding-top:7px;padding-left:5px;width:250px;height:30px;">
         </div>
    </div>
</script>
</div>
 <!-- end .intro -->
```

I am using Kendo UI Web

Attaches is an image thai I want to do, and tips will be pleased to receive, I have a couple of days looking for it, 
Regards,

Victor
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your already most of the way there.

All your missing is a button in your html and a call back. The way I went about this is just a normal button that isn't tied to anything in the html. However in the JS, on the render event of the list view, you will want a jquery selector that grabs all the elements of the list view. You can then .each on these and add a click event to the button passing the id of the element the given button is on. The click handler can take this id as a parameter and use it to look up the appropriate item in the data source. And then using the form data you can do whatever you want with it, such as make your ajax request.

Oh and a gottya I discovered is that every time the listview repaints itself, kendo will recreate the entire list in the dom using your template. So any buttons you had tied up in jquery for events will, effectively be new buttons. So this is what I suggest putting the bind code in the listview event for painting. So you can be sure it will fire at the right point.